# java jetty Maven websocket application runs on localhost:8080

Tags: java, web, websocket, server, jetty

I have a websocket web application that I run with Maven on Jetty. 
With all the settings that I did in my client, server and web.xml files, I expect the application to be run on localhost:8080/wsservlet. However, I can only run it on localhost:8080.
Can anyone help me understand why and how to solve this? thanks.

**MyServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(name = "WebSocketServlet", urlPatterns = { "/wsservlet" })
public class MyServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

   @Override
   public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
          factory.register(MyWebSocket.class);
   }
}
```

and
 
**MyWebsocket.java**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/wsservlet") 
public class MyWebSocket {
    ...
}
```

in my **html file**, I also create a websocket:

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/wsservlet");
```

my **web.xml**:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>WebSocketApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/wsservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to mix Jetty Native WebSockets (the `WebSocketServlet` and `WebSocketServletFactory` bits) with JSR356 WebSockets (the `@ServerEndpoint` bits).

That wont work.

Use one, or the other.

What you should do

1. Delete the `MyServlet` entirely
2. use Jetty 9.2+
3. configure your `${jetty.base}/start.ini` for `--module=websocket`

Comment: Thank you Joakim, The reason I added the Servlet was because I hoped to be able to create a war file from the project later (which I haven't been able to do yet, it seems something is not right); and I didn't think creating a war was possible without having a servlet (to enter the servletin web.xml). Is it possible to solve the above problem and also be able to make a war file? Thanks a lot.